# C program - lvalue required as left operand of assignment -

Tags: c, lvalue

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int N,i ,j ,m ;
int T[i][j] ;
do{
    printf("Saisir N");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    i=N ; j=N;
}while(N>10 && N<0);
for(m=1;m<(N/2);m++){

    for(i=1;i<N;i++){

          for(j=1;j<N;j++){
                if ( i=(m-1) && j=(N-m+1)){ // i get the error in this line
                    T[i][j]=m;
                }
                if ( i=(m-1) && j=(m-1) ){  // i get the error in this line
                    T[i][j]=m;
                }
                if ( i=(N-m+1) && j=(N-m+1) ){ // i get the error in this line
                    T[i][j]=m;
                }
                if (i=(N-m+1) && j=(m-1)){ // i get the error in this line
                    T[i][j]=m;
                }
          }

    }
}
}
```

I get this error " lvalue required as left operand of assignment" in the lines with "if conditions" i dont know where the problem is . Thank you

Comment: Aside `while(N>10 && N<0)` can never be true. Perhaps `while(N>10 || N<0)`.

Comment: Hint: operator precedence for `=` and `&&`. Are you sure you need `=` there?

Comment: Are you sure you want `=` equate and not `==` comparison? The `=` will interfere with the controlling loops.

Comment: Try changing `=` to `==` in all the if statements. That is the relational operator which I assume you want. Right now you're assigning values to i and j in those ifs.

Comment: you guys are right how could i forget it . thank you

Comment: While I agree what using `=` rather than `==` is the cause of the problem, I wouldn't expect an error of the form of  "lvalue required as left operand of assignment" for the offending statements.   For example, in  `if ( i=(m-1) && j=(N-m+1))`, both `i` and `j` are variables so they CAN be lvalues.      That suggests the OP hasn't been particularly precise, either in the nature of code posted or description of the error messages.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( i=(m-1) && j=(N-m+1))
```

Higher precedence of && than = cause

```
(m-1) && j
```

to be evaluated first, so this become

```
if ( i=((m-1) && j)=(N-m+1))
```

"=" have right to left associativity so next operation will be

```
((m-1) && j)=(N-m+1)
```

Left side is not modifiable lvalue, (as intermediate steps have no storage allocated for them) causing lvalue required on left side error.

May be what you intended is

```
if ( i==(m-1) && j==(N-m+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting the error is because  `if (i = something)` does not do what you think it does. You need the relational operator `==` which checks for equality.
NOT `=`.

So, in your if statements' conditions, change the `=`s into `==`s.