# Function LValue in C Return Not Specified

Tags: c

I am trying to organize a C program and then generate a lex file. But there is one last error in the code that I don't understand

I have never worked with C before.

The first part of the code with the error:

```
/* addChar - a function to add nextChar to lexeme */
void  addChar() {
  if  (lexLen <= 98) {
    lexeme[lexLen++] = nextChar;
    lexeme[lexLen] = 0;
  }
  else
    printf("Error - lexeme is too long \n");
}

/* getChar - a function to get the next character of 
             input and determine its character class */
 void getChar() {
   if  ((nextChar = getc(in_fp)) = EOF) {
     if  (isalpha(nextChar))
      charClass = LETTER;
     else if  (isdigit(nextChar))
           charClass = DIGIT;
          else  charClass = UNKNOWN;
   }
   else
     charClass = EOF;
}
```

The Error is:

````
program.c: In function ‘getChar’:
program.c:96:34: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
    if  ((nextChar = getc(in_fp)) = EOF) {```
````

Comment: Where and how is `nextChar` defined?

Comment: Change `= EOF` to `== EOF`. The preceding `nextChar = getc(in_fp)` isn't an lvalue, so it can't be the target of an assignment.

Comment: It's just a typo, `= EOF` should be `== EOF`.  With a single `=`, it's trying to assign to an assignment expression, which is what's generating the error.

Comment: Its a _typo[graphical error]_ when when one thing was intended but another was typed.  But when purposeful syntax results in unexpected behavior, it is something else.  Not a _typo_.  OP is presenting a question about a side-effect that occurred using intended syntax, evidenced by surrounding context in the post.  It may be futile to vote against the tide to reopen this question, but I've seen too many vote-to-close closures on questions by new programmers that are presented as an effort to understand a side-effect of something  caused by syntax they intended, then glibly discarded as a typo

Comment: @ryyker: Actually, the error message is quite easily searched. E.g. [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47371338/c-program-lvalue-required-as-left-operand-of-assignment) is also about using `=` instead of `==` in `if` condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
if  ((nextChar = getc(in_fp)) = EOF) {
```

Should be

```
if  ((nextChar = getc(in_fp)) == EOF) {
                              ^^
```

This changes the expression from an assignment to an evaluation, thus removing the need for an `lvalue`

Comment: Don't post answers to typos.  Just close the question.